# support for nolock in SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, nolock

Does anyone have an idea as to why SQL Azure does not support `with nolock` SQL statements. Does Microsoft has any plans of supporting this in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried running a nolock query on SQL azure and it works. That got me thinking that the statement is ignored because technically you don't have the option to set the database option (READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT and ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION). I'm guessing this is the reason but I'll try and do some more digging.

*Note: this is an Azure limitation.*

You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336245.aspx#isolevels):

> Both the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT and ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION database
>   options are set to ON in SQL Azure Database. Because SET
>    in the ALTER DATABASE Transact-SQL statement is not
>   supported, these database options cannot be changed. For more
>   information on row versioning-based isolation levels, see
>   Understanding Row Versioning-Based Isolation Levels.

**Update:** after a quick discussion with two über SQL experts, the solution appears to be to use a query like:

```
set transaction isolation level READ UNCOMMITTED
select * from myTestTable
```

So for every batch, you need to specify the isolation level.